# Robust M-estimator of location and dispersion by hand in R

Tags: r, statistics

I try to estimate a location and dispersion model with R, as described [Maronna et al (2006, pp. 56)](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470010924.html). However, my estimate dispersion does not converge to the desired value. Do I have an error in the code?

```
    #set.seed(12345)
    n <- 100
    error<-rnorm(n,0,1)
    x <- 10+5*error

    # funcion bisquare
    psi_bisq <- function(y){
      k <- 2.2
      ifelse(abs(y)<=k,ind <- 1,ind <- 0)
      return(y*ind*(1-(y/k)^2)^2)
    }

    # derivada de la funcion bisquare
    psi_bisq_der <- function(y){
      k <- 2.2
      ifelse(abs(y)<=k,ind <- 1,ind <- 0)
      return(ind*(1-(y/k)^2)*(1-5*(y/k)^2))
    }

    # funcion rho_bisquare
    rho_bisq <- function(y){
      k <- 2.2
      ifelse(abs(y)<=k, sal <- 1-(1-(y/k)^2)^3, sal <- 1)
      return(sal)
    }

    # segunda derivada de funcion rho_bisquare 
    rho_bisq_der2 <- function(y){
      k <- 2.2
      ifelse(abs(y)<=k, sal <- 6*(1-(y/k)^2)*(1-5*(y/k)^2)/k^2, sal <- 0)
      return(sal)
    }

    # funcion de peso
    W <- function(dato){
      ifelse(dato==0, ww <- psi_bisq_der(0), ww <- psi_bisq(dato)/dato)
      return(ww)
    }

    Wdis<-function(dato){
      ifelse(dato==0,ww<-rho_bisq_der2(0),ww<-rho_bisq(dato)/dato^2)
    }

    #======== Estimador simultáneo de localización y dispersión 

    # estimador robusto de dispersi?n
    sigma_est_a <- median(abs(x-median(x)))/0.6745

    # estimador robusto de la media, inicial
    mu_est_a <- median(x)

    epsilon <- .00001
    err1 <- epsilon*sigma_est_a
    err2<-epsilon
    error <- 1000
    error2<- 1000
    delta <- .9
    iter<-0

    while((error>=err1) && (error2>=err2)){
      pesos_loc <- rep(0,n)
      pesos_dis <- rep(0,n)
      for(i in 1:n){
        r <- (x[i]-mu_est_a)/sigma_est_a
        pesos_loc[i] <- W(r)
        pesos_dis[i]<-Wdis(r)
      }
      iter<-iter+1
      mu_est_n <-sum(pesos_loc*x)/sum(pesos_loc)
      sigma_est_n<-sqrt(((sigma_est_a^2)/(n*delta))*sum(pesos_dis*r^2))
      error <- abs(mu_est_n - mu_est_a)
      error2 <- abs(sigma_est_n/sigma_est_a -1)
      mu_est_a<-mu_est_n
      sigma_est_a<-sigma_est_n
    }
    sigma_est_a
    mu_est_a
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't put `rm(list=ls())` into a code you are asking someone else to post. Please post a minimal example. It might help the community if you post the question you are trying to answer, provided it is not copywrite protected.

Comment: It is not a question of that particular book. It comes from the content of a chapter, as you say I can not post because of copyright issues. However, I think it is common for a statistician.

Comment: Perhaps cross validated is a better place for this. I am aware of M estimation, but I am not quite sure you are asking a specific question. Perhaps you can paraphrase the model you are trying to build, provide some details of the algorithm you are trying to use to estimate the parameters of the model, and provide some insights into where you think it has gone wrong.

Comment: As well as provide the "desired result".

Comment: You're right. It may be a question best for Cross Validated. The results, however, must converge to the specific values of the model x = mu + sigma * error. With mu = 10 and sigma = 5. Indeed, it is pretty close to mu, but not sigma.